# what are the best ways to transfer large streaming data files to cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, sftp

Is it possible to use aws kinesis? If possible how can we use it?
Any suggestions Please reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is unclear and therefore difficult to answer. Could you please update your question with more details about your requirements and tell us what you have tried so far? We will then be better able to offer some answers.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use aws kinesis?

Yup. You can pretty much use anything for anything these days. Just need a little bit of creativity, that's all.

> If possible how can we use it?

Good starting point would be the [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/kinesis/) but it would really depend on what you want to use it for.

> what are the best ways to transfer large streaming data files to cloud

That's hard to answer without any details. In the end, you will be only given options and opinions, it'll be your call to figure out what's best. Kinesis is reliable and works for basic use-cases but it can be slower and less flexible than other options. It also costs a pretty penny if you use it unwisely. If you need options, checkout [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/)

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I want  to transfer like 5TB of audio files securely from datacenter to cloud, where we can make use of the data, using FTP and scp would be a wrong option because it is very slow, we can also use direct connect to increase the data rate. I need a good option to transfer the data.